# Moving excel formulas to another range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need a way to make a button that would delete values on one sheet and move cell formulas on another sheet to the next row down.

For example, 'Sheet1' has the total amount of items produced on a given day for five different item categories. Those totals are summed up at the bottom of a table on Sheet1. Sheet2 takes that total and calculates a formula for the total tonnage produced on a given day for each item category on a row with the title date '6/19/20'.

I made a button that clears the contents of Sheet1, which operators will press everyday, but I also want to move the formuala on Sheet2 from row '6/19/20' to row '6/20/20' and delete the formula from row '6/19/20'. Here's the only code I have since I don't know where to begin:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ItemProductionData").ClearContents
```

Comment: Maybe use the macro recorder here? That might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Jaylan, did you want the contents of the rows of the date 19/06/20 to remain but the formula to move down? like a paste values?  Can you show the formula and the sheets please?  Sounds like i could help with this one :-D